# Can anyone tell me why I have this text in the terminal of IntelliJ?

Tags: java, terminal

I was learning how to code for the first time in my life and I started with Java. When I open the terminal like the tutorial shows I don't have $ but I have all this mess:

```
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
PS C:\Users\utente\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\src\com\company>
```

What can I do to fix it? I can't write what the guy in the tutorial writes

Comment: Because on Windows the default shell is PowerShell. If the tutorial only works in bash: time to find a better tutorial. However, with java properly installed, `java` and `javac` (and all the other java CLI utilities) should work just fine in PowerShell. Of course, linux-specific commands won't, but many have windows equivalents.

Comment: (and of course, "check your IDE's documentation" always applies, if you need a different shell in intellij, start at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html)

Comment: Can you explain everything for a person that does not anything about these things? I opened that tutorial just yesterday and all you explained is something completely unknown to me. All I did so far is to launch hello world.

Comment: Software runs on layers, an IDE is an Integrated Development Environment, IntelliJ is one, Eclipse is another, Visual Studio is another.  Mike is saying that IntelliJ has an terminal emulator, that is, IntelliJ will launch whatever shell you want.  An shell is another word for terminal.  The terminal is where you enter text input and is the interface computers had before GUI's were created.  GUI is an graphical user interface.  This web browser you are reading this in is an gui.  Windows interface is an GUI.   There are two main types of terminals, Windows based and Linux based.

Comment: But what can I do if I can't use my terminal on IntelliJ like the person of the tutorial I'm following? (also looked for other ones and it is the same)

Comment: It looks like this:  (1) You have Windows, not Linux.  (2) The author of the tutorial is writing instructions for someone who has Linux, not Windows.  What to do?  Find a tutorial written for Windows users.